# DevicePolicyManager Error: Unknown admin: ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, adb

I want to enable kiosk mode to my app. I have `AdminReceiver.java` in the same package with `MainActivity.java`. I already factory reset my phone, installed the app and then ran this command to make my app as device owner.

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.azecsoft.azeckiosk/.AdminReceiver
```

But, somehow I keep getting error message like this :

```
Error: Unknown admin: ComponentInfo{com.azecsoft.azeckiosk/com.azecsoft.azeckiosk.AdminReceiver}
```

This is how I set up the receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```html
<receiver
        android:name=".AdminReceiver"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Am I missing a step? Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Did you cerated device owner?